# Detected file changes on Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, tfs

How can I show detected file changes TFS on VS 2012's TFS as I can see on Visual Studio 2015.

I have Visual Studio 2015 installed on my personal laptop but I use another one from my company that has VS 2012 and.

I make some local (offline) changes (using notepad) and would be important to me seeing these changes.

Any help?

Comment: It is a bit unclear from your question, if you want to be notified about changes on the same machine or on the other.

Comment: Sorry, let me explain better. In my personal laptop I use VS 2015 for a personal project and it shows me every offline changes I do in the project structure, as you can see in this picture: http://i1.wp.com/www.12qw.ch/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/image.png .

In the company's machine I use VS 2012 because they can't update to 2015. But VS 2012 does not show me detected files.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement can't be achieved. Only when you use a **local Workspace**, and change something outside Visual Studio, your workspace detects the changes. But your VS 2015 and VS 2012 install on different machine, which means you are using two local workspace, so you are not able to see the detected changes in VS 2012 on your company's computer.

You may promote the changes and check them in in VS 2015 on your personal laptop, then you can get the changes in VS 2012 on your company's computer.

Comment: Please take a look at my comment above. Thanks!

Comment: @jhosefmax I understand your scenario, but your requirement can't be achieved. Only when you use a local Workspace, and change something outside Visual Studio, you'll see the detects changes in VS, but local workspace can't be seen on other machine.

Answer (score 0):

All file edits are performed locally and the edits cannot be seen by everyone else until they have committed (check-in) or shelved. Normally Visual Studio is used for editing the files, and it will mark the files as checked-out by you, so your team members can see that you are working on them.

If you use another editor than Visual Studio the files will not be checked out and no one can see that you are in the process of editing the files. You will then have to do a check-out of the file before you can make a check-in.

You can add an [e-mail Alert](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-US/docs/work/track/alerts-and-notifications) for when changes are committed to a file or folder, but again this only lets you know when a check-in is performed.